# Passing an already instantiated object as a new object

Tags: c#

This question may sound strange, also please forgive me as my program flow is probably all wrong, but any help on my situation is greatly appreciated!

I have a class called `EnemyFighter`, it has all the information in it like HP, Attack strength, etc. When the program starts it adds different types of enemies to a list, like so:

```
// Build enemies
Enemies = new Dictionary<int, EnemyFighter>();

Enemies.Add(1, new EnemyFighter());
Enemies[1].Name = "Beaver";
Enemies[1].SetLevel(1);

Enemies.Add(2, new EnemyFighter());
Enemies[2].Name = "Unicorn";
Enemies[2].SetLevel(3);
```

Then I have enemy groups, so you can fight multiple enemies, maybe two beavers lets say:

```
// Enemy groups
EnemyGroups = new List<EnemyFighter[]>();

EnemyGroups.Add(new EnemyFighter[] { Enemies[1] }); // Beaver
EnemyGroups.Add(new EnemyFighter[] { Enemies[1], Enemies[1] }); // Beaver x2
EnemyGroups.Add(new EnemyFighter[] { Enemies[2] }); // Unicorn
```

But when I went to run the application, upon attacking one of the enemies (when against the two beavers) I realized I was attacking "both" because essentially both "beavers" were the same object.

Could someone advise me on a better way to set up this kind of situation, where I have a template of an object, but want to pass a unique version of it into a list. Something like this:

```
EnemyGroups.Add(new EnemyFighter[] { new Enemies[1], new Enemies[1] });
```

Once again any help is appreciated thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to make your EnemyFighter class implement ICloneable

Comment: as variant method [Clone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.clone(v=vs.110).aspx). Another variant: create subclass for all enemy, and just create instance of this type

Comment: Use prototype design (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) pattern

Comment: `Name` here is really name for enemy or it rather enemy type?

Answer (score 2):

"Copying" objects isn't a trivial thing and in most cases is also not desirable.

In this scenario the neatest approach is probably to do something like this:

```
public class EnemyPrototype
{
    public string Name  { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
}

public class EnemyProvider
{
    private Dictionary<string, EnemyPrototype> _prototypes = 
        new Dictionary<string, EnemyPrototype>();

    public void AddPrototype(string key, EnemyPrototype prototype)
    {
        _prototypes[key] = prototype;
    }

    public EnemyFighter GetEnemy(string key)
    {
        var prototype = _prototypes[key];

        var fighter = new EnemyFighter();
        fighter.Name = prototype.Name;
        fighter.SetLevel(prototype.Level);

        return fighter;
    }
}
```

Now you can create your new enemy prototypes like this (assuming a private `EnemyProvider` instance member called `_provider` - adjust to your structure):

```
_provider = new EnemyProvider();
_provider.AddPrototype("Beaver", new EnemyPrototype {Name = "Beaver", Level = 1});
```

And get a new one like this:

```
var enemy = _provider.GetEnemy("Beaver");
```

So adding your two beavers becomes:

```
EnemyGroups.Add(new EnemyFighter[] { _provider.GetEnemy("Beaver"),
                                     _provider.GetEnemy("Beaver") });
```

You could also add a method to your `EnemyProvider` class that lets you pass an `int` and gives you back an array of enemies!

Comment: I might be missing something but this is just a more reuseable way of creating a new object with the same properties. You are creating a new object just getting properties from somewhere other than another object of type EnemyFighter. I would argue this is no different.

Comment: @Dhunt the point is to avoid restating all of the initial property values for new enemies when they are the same every time. This is exactly what this solution does. There's no actual use case here for cloning objects as the goal is to create enemies from the same *seed*, not copy an existing one.

Comment: ... creating a separate type to contain just the members needed to instantiate an enemy (and not all of the other stuff that is likely in an actual enemy instance) is just a matter of good separation of concerns. I can understand using an instance prototype kind of pattern when the plan is to override functionality on a per-instance basis but in this situation it just seems mixed up.

Comment: I can see the benefits and not arguing that this is not a better way of doing it. Would just say that in essence it's still cloning an object albeit, from a simplified type.

Answer (score 0):

So as you say the reason you are attacking both is that they are essentially the same object. To combat this you should copy the object. You could create a method like this:

```
private EnemyFighter DuplicateEnemy(EnemyFighter original){
    var newEnemy = new EnemyFighter(){
        Name = original.Name
    };
    newEnemy.setLevel(original.Level);
    return newEnemy;
}

EnemyGroups.Add(new EnemyFighter[] { DuplicateEnemy(Enemies[1]) }); // Beaver
EnemyGroups.Add(new EnemyFighter[] { DuplicateEnemy(Enemies[1]), DuplicateEnemy(Enemies[1]) }); // Beaver x2
EnemyGroups.Add(new EnemyFighter[] { DuplicateEnemy(Enemies[2]) }); // Unicorn
```

This will return a new object with the same values and you can add that to the list.

You could also take a look at AutoMapper which is a library used for copying objects and is quite flexible, I have used it in projects before and found it very helpful. http://automapper.org/

Comment: Instantiating one object and then cloning it really is not the best way of creating multiple objects with the same properties - what is needed here is a factory.

Comment: @Grundy Subclasses would work but may be limiting (e.g. if enemy types need to be definable at runtime).

Comment: @AntP, do you mean polymorphism here?

Comment: No - what I mean is that with subclasses all of the concrete enemy types have to be known at compile time (even if you use polymorphism to make them interchangeable). By creating a factory that lets you push new sets of properties as new enemy types, you can actually define new types of enemy at runtime (dynamic/customisable enemy types). Unless you are actually going to override functionality I think polymorphic/subclassed enemy types are overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `MemberwiseClone()` method to create a shallow copy of the 'template' object when adding it to the dictionary.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspX

Or you could implement a method to make a deep copy of your object.
Examples to create both shallow copy and deep copy are given in the `MemberwiseClone()` link above.

Comment: Cloning objects is a naive (and very silly) solution to this problem. Totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, you are referencing the same object multiple times in your array.  The bottom line is you'll need to put in distinct new object instead of the same reference.

My recommended approach is to make some sort of factory that will create and return a new enemy.  This has the benefit of being able to create an enemy from a generic stock of enemies, without having to worry about any modifications you made before a clone.

```
public static class EnemyFactory
{
    public static EnemyFighter MakeBeaver()
    {
        var beaver = new EnemyFighter
        {
            Name = "Beaver",
            Level = 1
        };
        return beaver;
    }
}
```

Then just create instances using the factory:

```
EnemyGroups.Add(new EnemyFighter[] { EnemyFactory.MakeBeaver(), EnemyFactory.MakeBeaver() }); // Beaver x2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to "clone" your initial object. Please take a look on `ICloneable` interface documentation and examples in the MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.clone(v=vs.100).aspx